# Ms-access. Several relationships possible?

Tags: ms-access, table-relationships

I have a small database about a DVD rental with three tables "Customers", "Movies" and "Rentals".
I created the following relationships:
Customers - Customer ID to Rentals - Cusotmer ID
Movies - Movie ID to Rentals - Movie ID

I would like to add the price field also from the movie table to the rentals table but when trying I'm getting told "A relationship already exists. Do you want to edit the existing relationship? To recate a new one click No". When I click "no" a new Movies table gets displayed is that correct as an outcome?

Thanks 
Nina

Comment: Price field as relation field?

Comment: What you are describing is a "behavior" of access. Instead of linking tables with 2 columns, it will create a second relationship with an other instance of the table. Not sure it correspond to your expectation.

Comment: hm okay but when I type a rented movie in my "rental table" it doesn't show me the price from the "movie table". Is that possible?

Comment: with an sql request yes

Comment: -.- okay I will give it a try and youtube it later. Thank you